# how to extract multiple values from json object using jq command

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to get multiple values from a json object.

```
{
    "nextToken": "9i2x1mbCpfo5hQ",
    "jobSummaryList": [
        {
            "jobName": "012210",
            "jobId": "0196f81cae73"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want `nextToken`'s value and `jobName` in one jq command.

Comment: Please share an example of how valid output data should look like. Since `jobName` is part of an array there could be multiple solutions. Also please share what you have already tried.

Comment: jq .nextToken, .jobSummaryList[].jobName
note that the json-line inserted above is incorrect - or incomplete you need to close the brackets.

Comment: I have tried following command :`jq '.jobSummaryList[]|select(.jobName|contains("23244"))'`

Comment: it looks like this:`{
    "nextToken": "9i2x1mbCpfo5hQ",
    "jobSummaryList": [
        {
            "jobName": "012210",
            "jobId": "0196f81cae73"
        }{
            "jobName": "123457",
            "jobId": "jhdktjjk"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: i want to extract either nextToken if present or jobName and JobId

Comment: and if that is not possible i want to get both nextToken and JobName and JobId.

Answer (score 3):

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

```
jq '.nextToken, .jobSummaryList[].jobName' file
```

Comment: `aws batch list-jobs --job-queue prd-worker-job-queue --job-status SUCCEEDED --region ap-northeast| jq '.nextToken, .jobSummaryList[].jobName[]|select(.jobSummaryList[].jobName=="305200210")'`